# Chemoselectively dihydroxylate a terminal alkene in the presence of an internal alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organotransition-metal-chemistry, synthesis

[image: en***ter image description here]
The goal is to dihydroxylate the exo alkene, and then convert to a ketone.

Any suggestions would be apprecitated to either chemoselectively convert the terminal alkene, or directly convert the terminal alkene to a ketone.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe complete gradual oxidation of methyl having allylic hydrogens would be better idea.

Answer (score 3):

The Lemieux-Johnson oxidation ([details here](https://www.synarchive.com/named-reactions/lemieux-johnson-oxidation)) using catalytic $\ce{OsO4}$ or $\ce{RuO4}$ turned over with $\ce{NaIO4}$ will do the transformation you want in one step. These conditions should be selective for the *exo* double bond.

Comment: Thank you! I was hitting a roadblock.

Comment: @Ellie If you are happy with this, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you want to make *(R)*-4-acetyl-1-methylcyclohex-1-ene? Do you have to start from *(S)*-limonene?

If not, consider the Diels-Alder reaction of isoprene and methyl vinyl ketone (e.g. https://doi.org/10.1039/B701333G , though this is not an enantioselective synthesis I imagine you can add chiral auxiliaries somewhere to increase that selectivity)

Comment: Thank you. I was considering that as well.